# PowerShell script to update config file based on env variables

Tags: powershell, file-manipulation

I am new to PowerShell and trying to accomplish few things here:

1. I have a zabbix agent configuration file and I want to be able to change  the zabbix_agent_win.conf.

   - Hostname
   - ServerActive
   - HostMetaDataItem

My ultimate goal is to be have a powershell script that will change the Hostname based on "$env:ComputerName" and ServerActive is to change with given parameter, HostMetaData with given parameter either env variable that can be populated with given cmdlet. I started playing around and came across with the following script:

```
$path = "C:\test.conf"
$word = $(Hostname) 
$replacement = $("$env:ComputerName")
$text = get-content $path 
$newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement
$newText > $path
```

However this script is not working for me and different combination which I have tried is not changing the value of hostname based on ("$env:ComputerName”).

I found another suggested option:

```
(Get-Content C:\test.conf -Raw).Replace('\$Hostname$\','\"$env:ComputerName"\') | 
Set-Content C:\test.conf
```

No luck yet,

Any help appreciated.

Thanks, 
Katherine

Comment: I'm trying to understand the context you're running this under, because I've attempted this with both local and remote PowerShell and $(Hostname) and "$env:ComputerName" resolve to the same value. I can only think it might be different if the environment variable had been modified somehow. Test by adding `$word -eq $replacement` to your script, which for me always returns `True`.

Comment: I have a config file that has Parameters such as: Hostname={MyCompName}, ServerActive={zabbix server hostname}, HostMetaData={system.uname}. I am trying to change these parameters using PowerShell script, the script should be able to find these parameters inside the config file and change according to the env variables. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your script is that it looks for the *actual* hostname value in the file and then replaces it. If your config file contains `HOSTNAME=MyComputer` and you run it on a computer called `MyComputer` then it will look up `MyComputer` in the file and replace it with the value of the `COMPUTERNAME` variable which is also `MyComputer`, resulting in no change to the file. If you put a placeholder like `Hostname={replace this text}` then `$(Hostname)` still resolves to `'MyComputer'`, not `{replace this text}`, the replace does not find or replace anything.

To find `Hostname=SOMETHINGELSE` and replace `SOMETHINGELSE` with `$env:COMPUTERNAME` requires a little more work.

### Regular Expression

This approach uses `-replace` rather than `.Replace()`, which allows use of regular expressions. It uses regular expression capture groups to find lines where `'Hostname='` appears. Because this is in brackets, it is called capture group 1, which is retained and stored in an automatic variable $1. This is kept by the processor and then repeated in the replace. Anything else on the line, represented by dot-asterisk (`.*`) (any character repeating 0 or more times, is then replaced by `$env:COMPUTERNAME`

```
(Get-Content "C:\test.conf" -Raw) -replace '(Hostname=).*',"`$1$($env:ComputerName)" | 
Set-Content "C:\test.conf"
```

If you do use this approach I would recommend reading up a bit more about regular expression capture groups so you know what this code is doing.

### Testing and replacing different parameters

Use this approach to test the logic. You can edit the bit between `@''@`  to represent values in your config file:

```
$zabbixserver='zabbix123'

@'
Hostname={MyCompName}
ServerActive={zabbix server hostname}
HostMetaData={system.uname}
'@ -replace '(ServerActive=).*',"`$1$zabbixserver" `
-replace '(Hostname=).*',"`$1$($env:ComputerName)"
```

Note the use of the 'backtick' to put the `-replace` lines on separate lines

Comment: `(Get-Content "C:\test.conf" -Raw) -replace `'(Hostname=).*',"`$1$($env:ComputerName)" | 
`Set-Content "C:\test.conf"` this worked and get the value of the comp name, however it get rid off the `Hostname` parameter. My goal is to have Hostname=MyServerName. How can I make sure that Hostname remains in the config file?

Comment: Did you miss out the backtick before `$1`? It's very important, it asks the processor to retain the text "Hostname=", without the backtick, the interpreter ignores the special purpose of `$1`. It should go, double-quote, backtick, dollar, one, dollar, open-bracket etc.

Comment: Somehow I missed backtick. Thanks so much! You saved tons of time for me. I will look at second part now.

Comment: No problem, if you feel my answer was correct, please close your question by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. It helps people know the question is already answered and gives feedback to the answerer.